# Is it possible to broadcast a message in Trello?

Tags: trello

I would like to know if it's possible to broadcast a message in Trello.

For example, to all members of an organization.

Answer (score 4):

This is not currently possible in Trello.

Comment: ..would be a useful tool, i++